# Will msa2324sa work with MSA60?

Tags: hardware, storage, hp, hp-modular-smart-array

We have an HP msa2324sa (HP MSA 2000 g2 sas) and need to expand storage.

Will the MSA60 work with the msa2324sa?

Will the MSA60 support 6TB drives?

We're looking at WD Red drives.  Why do they say 1-8 bays in the drive documentation?

Would the 1-8 bays apply in case they're in the MSA60?  Can I add 12 WD Red 6TB drives to the MSA60 and have a single volume?

We're looking at RAID6 or RAID50, perhaps using 1 or 2 drives as spares.

This is primarily for file storage and backups, so SATA is ok for us.

Thanks for any information or pointers provided.

Comment: We have tried the MSA60 with 4TB drives, it did not work.  It would only recognize 2.2TB, which seems to point to a 32-bit LBA somewhere...?  So, going to try 2TB drives next.

Comment: To wrap this up, we couldn't get the 4TB drives to work with the msa2324sa.  We also could not get the firmware to upgrade on the I/O modules of the MSA60.  We were getting an error that MSA60 is not supported.  So, we returned everything and went with MSA70 and 25 1TB HP SATA midline drives.  Thanks so much to the supplier for helping and being flexible.  We were able to successfully update the I/O firmware on the MSA70.  It works, but much less space than hoped for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using an D2600 unit instead of the MSA60, but it will technically work when cascaded from your MSA2324 unit.

6TB drives... 4TB disks are known to work in that enclosure, so the 6TB will likely work.

I wouldn't use SATA for a JBOD expansion because (depending on your cabling choice) you'll lose the dual-port/dual-pathing that the SAN expects. If going for large drives, the best option is nearline SAS.

If you use simplex cabling, this should all work.

The MSA2324 can't have array groups comprised of more than 16 disks. So 12 should be fine. I'd use RAID6 and keep a spare.

Comment: Because of your suggesting, I'm assuming the D2600 will work with the MSA2324sa.

Comment: The last comment was supposed to be a question...

Comment: The MSA60 and MSA70 are period-correct with the MSA2324. But the D2600 and D2700 should also work.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  We will be researching the D2600 and pricing the SAS drives.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find an official confirmation for this sorry but I did find one for the MSA2324sa working with an MSA70 - which was the SFF version of the MSA60 - so I'd certainly place a small wager that it'll work and probably be supported. That said like ewwhite I also hate the idea of using non-HP disks in HP storage, you don't need to look far on this site to hear tales of woe regarding these configurations and they're certainly not supported by HP as you can imagine.